# Refresh tab name from result of getName()

Tags: java, swing, data-binding, jtabbedpane

I'm adding a custom component to a `JTabbedPane`. The title of the tab is determined by `getName()` in the component. Now at some point the result of `getName()` changes, but the tab title is not automatically refreshed (as can be expected). How can I make it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time your component's name is changed, it could throw a `PropertyChangeEvent`. When the component is added to the tabbed pane, you could add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the component, listening for changes of its `name` property, and updating the tab name accordingly.

Don't forget to remove the listener when the component is removed from the tabbed pane, though.

Comment: "and updating the tab name accordingly." - What should I call for that? I'm not ever calling `setTitleAt()` on the pane right now, but the pane itself calls `getName()` on the component. Of course I could just call `setTitleAt()`, but is that correct?

Comment: Never mind, I've looked at the tabbed pane source. It simply calls `getName()` once, when adding the tab, and never after, so it seems I should just use `setTitleAt()`.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom I saw that too, but I lost link and forgot about ***, but this issue was Look and Feel rellated,

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom sounds like the tabbedPane is a custom component as well? If so, the best place for the propertyChangeListener is that custom tabbedPane itself: let it register the listener to the component on insert and unregister on remove

Comment: @kleopatra No it's a default `JTabbedPane`